# How to clip image in fabricjs version 4 beta

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I updated fabricjs for new control feature.

But my old image clipping is not working anymore since `clipTo` in `fabric.Object` is removed in new version.

How can I clip image without using `clipTo`, in change log they said I should use `clipPath` instead.

```
img.set({
        clipTo: function (ctx) {
           ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
           ctx.arc(0, 0,300, -Math.PI/6, -Math.PI+Math.PI/6 , true);
        }
    });
```

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mudin/z75nvgqs/)

Also this official demo  won't work in version 4 beta
http://fabricjs.com/clipping

Answer (score 2):

So, `clipTo` is deprecated since version 2 and was removed in version 4. The correct way of clipping is to use the `clipPath` property. Here is a simple example:

```
var radius = 150;
var clipPath = new fabric.Circle({
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    radius: radius,
    startAngle: 0,
    angle: Math.PI * 2,
    originX: "top"
});

fabric.Image.fromURL("../public/pug_small.jpg", function(img) {
    img.scale(0.5).set({
        left: 100,
        top: 100,
        angle: -15,
        clipPath: clipPath
    });

    canvas.add(img).setActiveObject(img);
});
```

Here is the official tutorial for the clipPath http://fabricjs.com/clippath-part1

Recent discussion about `clipPath` in the beta 4 version: https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/issues/6159

And a sample SandBox demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-60664120-fabric-js-400-beta8-mi0y7

Comment: I think it is good answer for circle clipping, but I needed sector clip

Comment: Recently the clipping demo was updated and shows also how to apply an animation to the clipPath: http://fabricjs.com/clipping

Answer (score 1):

I found temporary solution but it is not really answer:

I draw circle and polygon

```
var radius = 100;
var start = -150*Math.PI/180
var end = -30*Math.PI/180
let point1 = new fabric.Point(
  (radius+1)*Math.cos(start),
  (radius+1)*Math.sin(start)
)
let point2 = new fabric.Point(
  (radius+1)*Math.cos(end),
  (radius+1)*Math.sin(end)
)
fabric.Image.fromURL('http://fabricjs.com/assets/pug_small.jpg', function (img) {
    img.scale(1).set({
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        clipPath:new fabric.Group([
        new fabric.Circle({
          originX:'center',
          originY:'center',
          radius,
          startAngle: start,
          endAngle: end,
          stroke:false,
          strokeWidth:6
        }),
        new fabric.Polygon([point1,{x:0,y:0},point2],{
          originX:'center',
          originY:'center',
          strokeWidth:6
        })
        ])
    );
    canvas.add(img).setActiveObject(img);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mudin/z75nvgqs/31/

Help me to find better solution

Comment: I think making a group of objects is the right way of doing it. This is how the `clipPath` was thought to work.